# Temporal complexity on mergesort is constant

Tags: c, sorting, time-complexity, array-algorithms

I wanted to try and do a C implementation but the results were strange because, when it came to the mergesort algorithm, given the length of the array (even if the its elements where pseudo-random thanks to rand()). Every time it finished running the complexity was actually the same. I know, trying to understand the "problem" this way is not easy so this is the code that I've been written/copied from the internet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define DIM 1000000

void merge(int*, int, int, int);
void mergesort(int*, int, int);
int complexity=0; //Complexity is the variable that counts how many times the program goes through the relevant cycles

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int v[DIM], i;
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));
  for(i=0; i<DIM; i++){
    v[i]=rand()%100;
    printf("%d\n", v[i]);
  }
  mergesort(v, 0, DIM-1);
  for(i=0; i<DIM; i++)
    printf("%d\t", v[i]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("iterations: %d\n", complexity);
  return 0;
}

void mergesort(int v[], int lo, int hi){
  int mid;
  if(lo<hi){
    mid=(lo+hi)/2;
    mergesort(v, lo, mid);
    mergesort(v, mid+1, hi);
    merge(v, lo, mid, hi);
  }
  return;
}

//This implementation is not actually mine, I got it from a site because I couldn't figure out why mine wouldn't run and order the input
void merge(int v[], int p, int q, int r) {
  int n1, n2, i, j, k, *L, *M;
  n1 = q - p + 1;
  n2 = r - q;
  //creation and initialization of the left and right vectors
  L=(int*)malloc(n1*sizeof(int));
  M=(int*)malloc(n2*sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    L[i] = v[p + i];
    complexity++;
  }
  for (j = 0; j < n2; j++){
    M[j] = v[q + 1 + j];
    complexity++;
  }
  //merging section
  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = p;
  while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
    if (L[i] <= M[j]) {
      v[k] = L[i];
      i++;
      complexity++;
    } else {
      v[k] = M[j];
      j++;
      complexity++;
    }
    k++;
  }
  //from what I understood this should be the section where what is left out gets copied inside        the remaining spots
  while (i < n1) {
    v[k] = L[i];
    i++;
    k++;
    complexity++;
  }
  while (j < n2) {
    v[k] = M[j];
    j++;
    k++;
    complexity++;
  }
  return;
}
```

I'll leave an image to a few trials I did with various sorting algorithms down here as well

[image: Data for the Mergesort trials are down in the corner, as you can see there is just a row of data simply because the complexity was constant and independent from the actual content of the vector]

Here is the question: is it normal to have the variable that counts temporal complexity constant? My initial thoughts were that it was due to bad implementation of the counter, I have no idea of how to prove it though simply because my knowledge of the algorithm is not that strong.
If that ends up being the correct answer can you direct me towards an implementation (not too complicated but still functional) of the counter to evaluate temporal complexity more precisely?

Edit: The columns A to I of the excel screenshot that I uploaded correspond to the length of the randomly generated array the values are: 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 1000000.

Comment: Do you mean that the iteration counter `complexity` had a constant value for a given input size, independent of the actual values of input data?

Comment: @Hulk, exactly that. For example, given a vector of 100 elements the output is always 1344 iterations of the cycles, or for a vector of 500 is 8976 cycles, indipendent from the actual values inside the vectors. I forgot to include the lengths of the inputs in the image, those are: 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 1000000

Answer (score 1):

No matter the contents of the arrays, the `merge` function increments `complexity` by `2(r-p+1)`. Since the `merge` function is the only part of the code that depends on the contents of the array, this shows that the `complexity` variable is incremented a fixed number of times overall.

Here's a sketch of why the `merge` function increments `complexity` by `2(r-p+1)`:

This block increments it by `n1`:

```
for (i = 0; i < n1; i++){
    L[i] = v[p + i];
    complexity++;
}
```

This block by `n2`:

```
for (j = 0; j < n2; j++){
    M[j] = v[q + 1 + j];
    complexity++;
}
```

In the remaining code, `i` and `j` start at 0, and at each step either `i` or `j` is incremented by 1 and `complexity` increased. When the function returns, `i` is `n1` and `j` is `n2`, so this adds another `n1+n2` to `complexity`.

Since `n1 = q-p+1` and `n2 = r-q`, overall the `merge` function increments complexity by `2*n1 + 2*n2 = 2(q-p+1+r-q) = 2(r-p+1)`.

Comment: So on a theoretical level my implementation of this counter to keep track of the number of iterations is correct and the merge function that I fetched on the web (and mergesort mindset in general) does not depend from the actual values inside the input vector; as would happen for, let's say, quicksort and insertionsort (that both, during my test, gave me slight variations of the number of cycles for the same input length). Does this make any sense?